# Java Swing Windows 10 Look and Feel

Tags: java, windows, swing, themes, look-and-feel

Is there a way to change the Windows 10 system look and feel instance in order to change the title bar color?

Here is an example of the result I'm looking for: [Dark title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jYKn.png)

Currently I'm running this line of code to get the system look and feel:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Ditch Swing and use JavaFX. You can make use of CSS to make extensive changes to the appearance of your UI.

Comment: Java doesn't control the title bar, so you can't change its color.

Comment: @camickr You're completely correct, however, you can hide the title bar using JavaFX and substitute an ersatz bar of your own creation.

Comment: *you can hide the title bar using JavaFX*  You can also do that with Swing. You use an undecorated frame (or dialog).

Comment: @MarsAtomic 
I had already considered this solution before, the only drawback is that I would like to keep all the functionalities that the title bar offers in the system in general; dragging, scaling, scaling by dragging to the sides of the screen, etc.

Comment: I LookAndFeel I have created offers a custom title bar without loosing any native OS features. If you want to you can see if it fits your purpose: https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf